# Mysql запрос по двухмерному массиву (фильтр)

Tags: mysql, массивы

Есть массив аттрибутов и их значений

```
arr = [
      attr [val, val, val],
      attr [val, val, val],
]
```

Нужно по этому массиву сделать запрос который будет выдавать все продукты, у которых атрибуты имеют такие значения.

Сам пока не придумал как сделать.
Для одного элемента :
`... WHERE attribute.value IN (val,val,val) AND attribute.name = attr`.

Так будет работать, но если добавить еще один такой же блок - получается нам выдаст лишние товары, ибо значения атрибутов могут пересекаться и, если нам нужен `val` только из этого атрибута, а мы получим и из остальных.

Буду благодарен за любую помощь

Comment: А как Вы "добавляете еще один блок"? Через `OR`? Разве такой вариант Вас не устроит: `WHERE (attribute.value IN (val,val,val) AND attribute.name = attr) OR (attribute.value IN (val2,val2,val2) AND attribute.name = attr2)`?

Comment: Написал что-то такое:
`$whereRaw = '';
   foreach ($filter as $key => $value) {
    if(!empty($value)) {
     $values = implode(',', $value);
     $whereRaw .= '(WHERE attibute.name = ' . $key . ' AND product_attrs_value.value IN (' . $values . ')) OR ';
    }

   }
$whereRaw = substr($whereRaw, 0, -3);`
$query->whereRaw($whereRaw);

Но на данный момент погряз в ошибки синтаксиса, сейчас попробую разобраться надеюсь заработает.

Comment: Структуру таблиц приведите. Думаю вам надо будет еще считать кол-во совпавших атрибутов count(distinct attibute.name) и убеждаться что из столько, сколько условий в запросе. Это вы все таки хотите получить товары у которых есть каждый из атрибутов

Comment: Таблиц 3:
attributes (id,name), product_attrs_value(id,product_id,attribute_id, value)
products(много полей)
Они joinнятся. В массиве у нас есть имена атрибутов и значения

Comment: Всем спасибо, реализовал действительно с помощью способа который описали в первом комментарии ( (--- and ---) or (--- and ---)  ) - все заработало.

Comment: @AndreyPetko, я внесу решение, как ответ, чтобы Вы могли закрыть вопрос... Будем повышать процент отвеченных вопросов в сообществе :)

Answer (score 1):

Вам надо реализовать такую конструкцию:

```
WHERE (attribute.value IN (val,val,val) AND attribute.name = attr) OR
(attribute.value IN (val2,val2,val2) AND attribute.name = attr2)
```